# Mysql query error, not equal to

Tags: sql, mysql

**If title is: $title = wp_title('',0); - query does not exclude: AND `posttitle` <> '$title'"
If title is for example:    $title = 'test is the best'; - query does exclude AND `posttitle` <> ''test is the best'"**

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT posttitle, posturl, siteurl, MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('$title') AS score FROM interlinks WHERE MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('$title') AND `posttitle` <> '$title'");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo - `posttitle` doesn't need single quotes, use:

```
SELECT posttitle,  
       posturl, 
       siteurl, 
       MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('$title') AS score 
  FROM interlinks 
 WHERE MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('$title') 
   AND posttitle <> '$lowercasetitle'
```

Putting single quotes indicates to SQL that it's dealing with a string, not a column reference.  So the comparison to your variable was that it didn't equal the string 'posttitle', rather than the value in the column.

In MySQL, backticks (`) are [used for escaping registered keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html):

```
SELECT posttitle,  
       posturl, 
       siteurl, 
       MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('$title') AS score 
  FROM interlinks 
 WHERE MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('$title') 
   AND `posttitle` <> '$lowercasetitle'
```

Comment: It works if u use another variable instead of $lowercasetitle... I think it's something wrong with the variable $lowercasetitle -- HERE IS THE CODE: $title = wp_title('',0); $lowercasetitle = strtolower($title); echo $lowercasetitle;

Comment: @webmasters: What does `echo wp_title('', 0)` return?

Comment: Check this out please: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title - about the  wp_title()

Answer (score 0):

Generally, string comparisons in mysql are not case sensitive because the tables by default use `latin1` character set and `latin1_swedish_ci` collation. To get them to compare in a case sensitive way, use the `BINARY` operand like this:

```
WHERE MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('$title') 
AND BINARY posttitle != '$lowercasetitle'
```